# CodeIgniter 4: Too few arguments to function" error in controller constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter, dependency-injection, constructor, autoload

I'm encountering an issue in my CodeIgniter project where I'm getting a "Too few arguments to function" error in the constructor of one of my controllers. I'm not sure why this error is occurring, and I need help resolving it.

**Error Message:**

> Too few arguments to function App\Controllers\RestAPI\V1\OTP\OTPController::__construct(), 0 passed in ...

**Controller Constructor:**

```
public function __construct(JWTService $jwtService, UserModel $userModel, ReferralCodeModel $referralCodeModel, ReferralHistoryModel $referralHistoryModel)
{
    $this->jwtService = $jwtService;
    $this->userModel = $userModel;
    $this->referralCodeModel = $referralCodeModel;
    $this->referralHistoryModel = $referralHistoryModel;
}
```

**What I've Checked:**

1. I've verified that the dependencies (JWTService, UserModel, ReferralCodeModel, ReferralHistoryModel) are properly configured in my CodeIgniter project.
2. I've checked my CodeIgniter configuration files (app/Config/Services.php and app/Config/Autoload.php) to ensure that the services and models are registered.
3. I've made sure there are no typos or namespace issues in my configuration files.
4. I've run composer dump-autoload to regenerate the autoloader files.

**Request for Help:
**
I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this error and correctly inject the required dependencies into my controller. If you have experience with CodeIgniter's dependency injection system and can provide insights into why this error is occurring, please share your expertise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error says `0 passed in…` so the constructor isn’t receiving any of the necessary four. It should also tell you where it is in your code where you‘re trying to instantiate the OTPController.

Can you show us the whole error message?

Somewhere in your code you would have something like this:

**Dependency Injection for Models and Libraries:**

```
//instantiating the model somewhere in your code
$model = new model();

//and then pass it to the OTPModel
$OTPModel = new OTPModel($model)

//OTPModel class:

class OTPModel {

    public function __construct($model){

          $this->model = $model;

    }
}
```

**For Controllers:**

load models in the __construct() instead of passing them as arguments:

```
class OTPController extends BaseAPIController
    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->userModel = new UserModel();
            ...
        }
```

**Update:**

**Use Codeigniter’s Services**

Or use Codeigniter’s Services functionality in order to get the benefits of Dependency Injection. Have a look at CI’s documentation under “Codeigniter 4 Overview->Services” and see if that helps.

Have a look at this link: https://www.patreon.com/posts/services-in-4-20830710

> Services are dependencies in your project. Using a Service, instead of just creating a new instance in the controller, gives you three main benefits:

> 1. Allows you to always get the same instance no matter how many times you call that Service.

> 2. You have a single place to setup the Service's dependencies.

> 3. If you ever need to swap out the service for another class that shares the same Interface, then you change that in the Service file, and it is now changed everywhere that you might have used that in your application.

Comment: `class OTPController extends BaseAPIController
{
    protected $jwtService;
    protected $userModel;
    protected $referralCodeModel;
    protected $referralHistoryModel;

    public function __construct(JWTService $jwtService, UserModel $userModel, ReferralCodeModel $referralCodeModel, ReferralHistoryModel $referralHistoryModel)
    {
        $this->jwtService = $jwtService;
        $this->userModel = $userModel;
        $this->referralCodeModel = $referralCodeModel;
        $this->referralHistoryModel = $referralHistoryModel;
    }

    
 Send OTP Method
}`

Comment: Error msg :    "title": "ArgumentCountError",
    "type": "ArgumentCountError",
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Too few arguments to function App\\Controllers\\RestAPI\\V1\\OTP\\OTPController::__construct(), 0 passed in /Users/rkbishnoi/Sites/localhost/FProject/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php on line 904 and exactly 4 expected",
    "file": "/Users/rkbishnoi/Sites/localhost/FProject/app/Controllers/RestAPI/V1/OTP/OTPController.php",

Comment: Thank you for the code. Anybody correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you can pass arguments to the controller's __construct() method. But you can pass parameters through the constructor in your own libraries. You can also load models in the controller using the `$this->model = new model()`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Using Dependency Injection, as shown in the code example, is generally considered a safer and more maintainable way to handle dependencies compared to using new ServiceName() directly within controller methods.

Comment: That’s absolutely correct. But I think DI should (can?) only be used in models and libraries. For controllers Codeigniter uses something called “Services”. Have a look at the CI documentation under Codeigniter 4 Overview->Services. Quote: It is recommended to only create services within controllers. Other files, like models and libraries should have the dependencies either passed into the constructor or through setter method.

Comment: So its not possible DI in controllers?

I found something any comment on this https://www.linkedin.com/advice/0/how-can-you-use-dependency-injection-php-frameworks

Comment: If you mean DI in the conventional way, I think the answer is no. If you mean achieving the same functionality as DI, then the answer is yes. ->see answer update.